# "MAS SMS-CDMA" Bluetooth service

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, sms

I have my phone (LG Rumor Touch on Sprint) connected to my Windows 7 computer by Bluetooth. Usually, one of the services is unidentified and no driver is installed. Occasionally I have an issue that is solved by removing and re-pairing my phone with my computer.

The last few times I have paired my computer and phone, the unidentified service was found and installed, as "MAS SMS-CDMA".

It sounds like an interface that allows sending and reading SMS messages via Bluetooth.  However, there is no software available from Sprint or LG that I have found that offers such functionality. Searching Google for "MAS SMS-CMDA" (with quotes) did not provide anything useful, only what appear to be CMDA information written in Spanish.  What can I use this service for, and how do I use it?
[image: Screenshot of Bluetooth Services]

#### EDIT

I re-paired my phone with my computer in Windows after using it in Linux, and the properties dialog still appears as in the screenshot above, but the Add New Hardware dialog shows it differently, reading Bluetooth Message Access, which is not shown in properties.  How can I make use of this feature? (I am using the WIDCOMM bluetooth drivers, latest version and have already done the obscure registry hack to keep them from messing up full-screen games with the Caps Lock indicator[image])

Answer (score 0):

I believe it allows the application to exceed the 160 Character SMS Limit. The SMS limit is 1120 bits or 160 characters.

Comment: My phone limits SMS to 160. If you type more than that, it sends multiple messages. But why would that show up on my computer as a Bluetooth service?

Comment: Not sure about the particular bluetooth device other than it probably allows larger text strings between the handheld device and whatever your connected to (ie perhaps a bluetooth keyboard).  I am pretty sure that is what the setting is for. The Digital Coding Scheme (DCS) signaling protocol was originally limited 140 octets, 140 x 8 bits = 1120 bits / 160 characters.